# remove hidden table rows and output .html to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to **remove** the `<thead>` and all table rows that are `:hidden`, then output the rest to my excel sheet... The problem is that it's not removing any rows, only hides them. When I view the outputted excel sheet, the rows are just hidden which I don't want...I want them completely removed so they don't show up in the excel output at all.

I would like to do this in one line if possible...right now i'm trying:

```
var body = $(tableElm).remove("thead").remove("tbody:hidden").html();
```

I've tried other ways as well like so:

```
var clone = $(tableElm + " tbody:visible").clone();
var body = clone.html();
```

But with all tries same result: Rows hidden -- not removed as I wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. But it will delete completely from the document all hidden elements inside the table

```
$('table *:hidden').remove();
var clonedItem = $($('table').html());
```

This is another option in which we just 'identify' the elements to be deleted so we can delete them later in the clonedItem

```
$('table *:hidden').attr('data-todelete', 'true');
var clonedItem = $($('table').html());
$('table *:hidden').removeAttr('data-todelete');
clonedItem.find('*:hidden').remove();
```